# Defining Web Service via VB.NET Code

Tags: vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2013

Good Day Everyone -

I'm using VB.NET within VS2013 (Professional) and have a question about defining a Web Service binding via code.

I can successfully had a Service Reference via Solution Explorer and connect to a specified URL for the web service I'm trying to access.

What I am looking for is some direction on how to define the endpoint via code; the web service I'm hitting will be local to each facility and I need to allow a user to define the endpoint URL on the fly.

Any thoughts or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a WCF service or a classic asmx webservice?

Comment: Great question and sorry I should have included that.  Currently WCF Services.

Answer (score 0):

After researching I found the problem.

When I connected to the Web Service VS stored the connection details in app.config in the folder of the project.  At run time, VS compiled the app.config into .config which had to go with compiled application.

Once I did this I was able to connect without a problem to the defined WS outside of VS.  Once basic connection details were present, I could successfully override the remote endpoint with whatever the user inputted.